# How to sort string alphabetically in shell script

Tags: shell

String sorting algorithm in shell script.

I have done it for numbers,but not able to do for string.

EX:- I am kohali.
It should be like
am i kohali

Comment: `echo "i am kohal" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | tr '\n' ' '`

Comment: In this way i have also done,but i need algorithm of it.               
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "filename"
read filename
for i in `cat $filename`;
 do
    echo $i
done | sort | tr '\n' ' '

Comment: Here are some sorting algorithms: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Sorting_Algorithms -- I don't think you'll find any of them actually implemented in shell though.

Answer (score 1):

Below script will help you

```
 str='I am kohali'
    for i in `echo $str`; do
        echo $i
    done | sort
```

Below one will accept input from user

```
read -p "Enter your string:" str
for i in `echo $str`; do
    echo "$i"
done | sort
```

**Output**

> am I kohali

Comment: I have written the same code above . Can you write algorithm to take input from user and then perform sorting .